# Flutter switch shadow effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How can I add shadow effects to the cupertino switch I am currently working on. Here is the result I want to achieve [image of switch with shadow effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrfLu.png). Can I get a code snippet if possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the switch with a `Container` and add `boxShadow` to it:

```
Container(
            child: CupertinoSwitch(
              activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  )
                ]
            ),
          ),
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: Consider using a `DecoratedBox` instead of a `Container` for  better performance.

Comment: @Derek Can you provide a snippet for it? It would be quick for me XD!

Comment: The performance difference is totally negligible! Won't make a change at all! @Derek

Comment: Just change the `Container` to `DecoratedBox`. No difference. @PrashantMishra

Comment: The `Container` widget doesn't have a `const` constructor and also, you won't be needing most of the properties the `Container` widget provides. SO that drops affects the performance, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You won't be able to measure it at all! @Derek

Comment: It's left to the OP to choose which way they want. Incase anyone wants to see a performance test, read here https://medium.com/@crizantlai/flutter-performance-analysis-of-const-constructor-d2a72fd8a043

Comment: @Mobina Thankful for this